# Error on "production" environment on Symfony2

Tags: deployment, symfony

I´m currently developing a web site using Symfony2.

On 'dev' environment everything works just fine, but when I try to access to the system with the `DEBUG` parameter on `FALSE` (trough app.php which invokes the appKernel with debugger disabled) the system throws a "`500 Internal Server Error`" when I try to load any section of the system.

I've already cleared the cache and warmed it up and this error keeps showing up.
I'm working with the standard distribution of Symfony (didn't change anything but the bundle I created) and this server: `Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8o PHP/5.3.4 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1 installed trough XAMPP`

How can I make the production environment work keeping the debugger disabled?

Comment: Check the Apache error log. You should see the exception message there.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The config.yml has disabled debug by default in production enviroment, you can see what was wrong (errors ect.) in log files app/logs/prod.log

Comment: The problem was a component looking on a directory on the cache that didn't existed. I've just found it. Thnx!