# Disable Error in Production Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-2.3

i have installed Symfony 2.7.41 and enabled production mode in app.php

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
```

when i tested in controller by making one eror

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        echo "dsgds";
        $var=dd;
        exit();

    }
```

but even in production showing erorr instead of 500 internal server error

> dsgds Notice: Use of undefined constant dd - assumed 'dd' in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\weebly\development-two\src\AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php
>   on line 17

Already read following 
[Dev Exceptions are shown in production environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23335375/dev-exceptions-are-shown-in-production-environment?rq=1)

[Moving app to production mode in Symfony 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258715/moving-app-to-production-mode-in-symfony-2)

[Symfony: disable exceptions in prod mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922231/symfony-disable-exceptions-in-prod-mode?rq=1)

[Error on "production" environment on Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934462/error-on-production-environment-on-symfony2)

Comment: add those that you already checked

Comment: @DeadManAlive.updated few still more referred now i dont have links

Comment: @vision does the error page in general work? (https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/controller/error_pages.html#testing-error-pages-during-development)

Comment: @fab.even i tried to create custom pages but my bad it only works for 404 not for fatal error or 500 internal server erorr.my aim is to hide fatal erorr and notice errors

Answer (score 0):

`dd` is undefined variable here.
if you want to set value of `$var` as string `'dd'` then it will be ok but here you don't put any `''`  . so it is behaving a constant variable which you previously not d efined.

thank you

Comment: i did that to check how it throwerror in production.my question is how we can hide errors in production.even in laravel we can hide when its live

Comment: @roabak if error throws in both production and dev then whats the use of disabling

Comment: Can you give me the url of checking it?

Comment: checking in localhost

Comment: localhost/project_name/web/app.php/route 
or
localhost/project_name/web/app_dev.php/route  ?
which one you using

Comment: I am using app.php

Answer (score 0):

As was said before dd should be in ' (as string)  to avoid error,  but as i understand it's not what you are asking .

You want to hide  exceptions ....

You may not like the anwser , but you sholdn't even try .
Honestly (it's a bad idea)  i don't know if it's even  possible  but you should start with  symfony event system .

Maybe **try to  catch kernel.exception  event  and  stop event propagation** .

Some tips how to do it should be here :

https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/controller/error_pages.html
https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/event_dispatcher.html

But it's a really a  bad idea - you as a guy who creates code should try to  do the code  without error, and  not hiding it  (that why exists  test and phpunit).
IMHO best thing in symfony is that this framework forces you to learn OOP and error/exception handling

**PS.second bad idea :**  maybe put all action code in try .. catch ?

Answer (score 0):

It may be dump, but, as it occurs on production mode, have you clean your cache ? (or even delete it to be sure).

Comment: @kalfei59.cache deleted